# ProgessBar is not visible,what is wrong and how to manage it

Tags: android, progress-bar

What wrong with Progress Bar it is not showing up.I am getting up the thing.I had Implemented following code in it.

1. Checked Internet connection
2. Added progress bar but not showing while loading webpage in Webview
3. What wrong in it any modification to make
4. I am doing to much work on main thread.

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView myWebView;
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
ProgressBar pgbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting()
            || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        myWebView=new WebView(this);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final Activity activity=this;

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        pgbar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pgbar.setMax(100);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in");
        MainActivity.this.pgbar.setProgress(0);
        setContentView(myWebView);
    }
    else {
        builder.setMessage("No Internet connection available.Would you like to connect ?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                builder.setMessage("So you want to exit");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog=builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient{

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int progress) {
        this.pgbar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `MainActivity.this.pgbar.setProgress(0);`  go through http://javatechig.com/android/progressbar-while-loading-webview

Comment: check this--> http://javatechig.com/android/progressbar-while-loading-webview

Comment: @AmarbirSingh I already post this link  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the webview as content view of the activity. `setContentView(myWebView);`

Comment: So  what changes I need to do

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: Layout only contain a progressbar and webview xml coding only

Comment: Then remove this line of code setContentView(myWebView);
Also replace this line myWebView=new WebView(this); with myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewid);